# ASP.NET Core - the model's id/key doesn't get a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a model in an ASP.NET Core project. The model has an "Id" property. When I want to save a model in the database, it says the model's Id is null. Here is the code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveMessage(MessageViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var message = new MessageModel
        {
            SenderName = await _userManager.GetUserNameAsync(await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User)),
            Title = model.Title,
            Email = model.Email,
            Message = model.Message,
            SavedDate = DateTime.Now,
            Sent = false
        };
        var userMessage = new UserMessage
        {
            ApplicationUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User),
            MessageModel = message
        };

        _context.MessageModel.Add(message);
        _context.UserMessage.Add(userMessage);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(HomeController.Home), "Home");
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(MessageController.EditMessage), "Message", model);
}
```

And here is the model:

```
public class MessageModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime SavedDate { get; set; }
    public bool Sent { get; set; }

    public List<UserMessage> UserMessages { get; set; }
}
```

How can I give a value to the Id?
Thank you!

Comment: Please post the relevant model code, and also tell us which model has the error.

Comment: if the Id is not in the model. it means you need to provide the value in the view, for example by using input hidden `@Html.Hidden()`

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your model definition, this is my guess:

Your Id is most likely the primary key which you are expecting the database to set. However, when you defined your model, you probably did not specify the Id property as the key, and in your code you are also not setting it, which is why it is null.

Answer (score 0):

If you are posting the model data from your webpage, then you may need a FromBody tag on that model property:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveMessage([FromBody] MessageViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
```

It's the .net Core's way of telling your action that it should try serializing from the request body.  It's a little different than model-binding in .Net ... err.. not-core...  what are we calling not-core now??

Anyway - [check it out](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).  It's just a guess -- but if the other properties in your model are ALSO null/defaults, then that's probably what's happening.

Comment: Ha. No way "full framework" sticks ... it sounds better-than-core and I can't imagine the marketing team in Redmond will sit idly by while that gains momentum.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found the exact answer but, after adding the input tag which is "id" in the form , I get Id in the model.

Example:[image]

, After that on controller I get the Id.